# How to position a child element at the bottom of a fixed position parent

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get `#needQuoteWrap` to be at the bottom of the `#sideContactWrap`. `#sideContactWrap` is a fixed element. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I put an inner container with `position:relative` and `height:100%`.

I have tried making `#needQuoteWrap` as `position:absolute`, but when I do that it disappears.

Does anyone know how I can get `#needQuoteWrap` at the bottom of `#sideContactWrap`?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9db698dp/)

```css
#sideContactWrap {
 background: #EDEDED;
 width: 30%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#sideContactInner {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.sideBlock {
 width: 90%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 0 5%;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid red;
 text-align: left;
}
.sideBlockText {
 margin: 0;
}
#needQuoteWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
#needQuote {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #b82222;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideContactWrap">
  <div id="sideContactInner">
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <h2 class="secTitle">Contact Info</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">Toll Free</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">Office Hours: Monday - Friday 8:00 am - 5:00 pm EST</p>
    </div>
    <div id="needQuoteWrap">
      <a href="#">
        <div id="needQuote">Need a quote?</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `#needQuoteWrap` element to have `position: absolute;`. Child elements are relative to the parent when the parent has a position set to anything other than `static` (the default).

The below example shows it's now at the bottom.

```css
#sideContactWrap {
 background: #EDEDED;
 width: 30%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#sideContactInner {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.sideBlock {
 width: 90%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 0 5%;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid red;
 text-align: left;
}
.sideBlockText {
 margin: 0;
}
#needQuoteWrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
#needQuote {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #b82222;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideContactWrap">
  <div id="sideContactInner">
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <h2 class="secTitle">Contact Info</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">Toll Free</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">Office Hours: Monday - Friday 8:00 am - 5:00 pm EST</p>
    </div>
    <div id="needQuoteWrap">
      <a href="#">
        <div id="needQuote">Need a quote?</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but I am getting the same results as I mentioned in my question. The needQuoteWrap disappears when I set it to position absolute

Answer (score 1):

> `position:absolute` to `#needQuoteWrap` is working as expected.

```css
#sideContactWrap {
  background: #EDEDED;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: -9px 0px 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#sideContactInner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.sideBlock {
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: left;
}

.sideBlockText {
  margin: 0;
}

#needQuoteWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#needQuote {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b82222;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideContactWrap">
  <div id="sideContactInner">
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <h2 class="secTitle">Contact Info</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">Toll Free</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBlock">
      <p class="dG sideBlockText">Office Hours: Monday - Friday 8:00 am - 5:00 pm EST</p>
    </div>
    <div id="needQuoteWrap">
      <a href="#">
        <div id="needQuote">Need a quote?</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```